# Split string to numbers with spaces

Tags: regex, split

I have a line which I need to split to three numbers (price, TAX, total price):

```
Total 17 387,25 3 477,50 20 864,75
```

Is it possible to do that? Important is that numbers needn't be thousands, this line is also valid:

```
Total 9999,99 1999,99 11 999,99
```

All dividers are spaces.

Thank you.

Comment: I think I dint get your question. You want to split and extract the numbers between the coma's?

Comment: No. Commas are decimal points. First line has 3 numbers:
17387,25 and 3477,50 and 20864,75, Look at TheHe's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(\d[\d ]*,\d+) ([\d ]+,\d+) ([\d ]+,\d+)
```

$1 = price
$2 = tax
$3 = total

Comment: Perfect! I love the power of regular expressions.
Thank you.